# Error: Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to add an external library to my existing project. I created a libs folder and added my MaterialDrawer library in the root directory. Here is my **settings.gradle** file:

```
include ':app'
include 'libs:MaterialDrawer'
```

But gradle sync is failed and getting following error:

> Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

I couldn't find any solution in SO regarding my problem. Anyone would be kind enough to help?

Here is the **build.gradle (Project)**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Here is the **build.gradle (app)**:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 38
    versionName "2.1.8"

    generatedDensities = []

}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(":libs:MaterialDrawer")
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
} in the project's gradle

Comment: Still getting the error. :(

Comment: @noob-Sci-Bot Do you have any jar libraries in `libs` directory? Post `build.gradle` for `MaterialDrawer`. And why you use `repositories` section in app `build.gradle`?

Comment: @DeKaNszn I don't have any jar library in the libs folder. Just downloaded the zip file from github, extracted it and pasted the folder in the libs.

Comment: @noob-Sci-Bot is it https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer ?

Comment: @DeKaNszn Yes, that's the one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `google()` was added in Gradle 4.0
You should use `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` on old versions

Also remove `repositories` section from your app `build.gradle` (you may merge it with root `build.gradle`)

Read how to add library to `build.gradle` [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#setup)

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Please tell my why it is related to my newly added external library ? Before adding it everything was just fine.

Comment: show build.gradle for this library

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my main concern is to modify the mikepenz library. If I compile directly by URL how can I modify it ?

Comment: My answer for using library (you didn't say about modifying). If you want to modify, then you should use it as module.

Comment: That's what I want to do. How can add it as module? Can you help me with that please ?